# How to stop inside an iteration of a loop to increase speed?Python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, python-requests

I am trying to loop over a list of objects and then once there's nothing in the URL, stop the code and then go to the next object, and then write all the data to one JSON file.

**Here is my code**

```
import json
import requests
from config import configs
from datetime import datetime

current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
header = {"Authorization": "Bearer <api_key>"}

pst_rec_path = 'path/to/folder'

# Get a list of pst's (there are 245)
all_psts = []
for i in range(1, 3):
    s = requests.Session()
    s.proxies = < my_proxy >
    resp = s.get("https://host/v1/psts?page={0}".format(i), headers=header, verify=False).json()
    
# Get only the values from the pst_id field and put them into a list   
full_psts = [item['pst_id'] for item in resp]
all_psts.extend(full_psts)

# get all the pst receipitent list
pst_rec_list = []
print(len(all_psts))

# This will loop over all the pst's. Since there's a pagination limit per page (max=1), I have to iterate each page until it's empty
for obj in all_psts:
    # Iterate over all the pages per page until it is empty
    for i in range(1, 5000):
        s = requests.Session()
        s.proxies = < my_proxy >
        resp = s.get("https://host/v1/psts/{0}/recipients?page={1}".format(obj, i), headers=header, verify=False).json()
        if resp:  # If theres data, append it to the pst_rec_list variable
            pst_rec_list.extend(resp)
        elif not resp:  # if not stop the loop and go to the next obj
            print(str(i))  # To see at which page number it stopped at
            break
        else:
            break

print(len(pst_rec_list))
with open(pst_rec_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(pst_rec_list, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=1, sort_keys=False, default=str)
```

Essentially, this script creates a full list of objects (pst's), which there's about 245 of them...Then loops over each object and writes its data to a JSON file. However, Since there's a pagination limit per page (max=1) on this API, I have to iterate each page until it's empty. This code works decent but takes forever. Is there a quicker and more efficient way to loop over each page, write the data to the JSON file, and then when there's nothing on the page, stop the current object loop and go to the next object? I am new to this so any ideas or suggestions would help.

Comment: Try using the keywork continue.

Comment: so after the first elif, use continue?

Comment: Yes, because that will just skip to the next part of the loop instead of ending the loop altogether (what break does).